# How to let some file to be visiable in QtCreator

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I'm using cmake to configure my project. It seems QtCreator only show those files referred by `add_executable`, `add_library` and `configure_file`. Other files in project directory are not visiable in the **Projects** panel.

Although we can still visit those files by file->open, it make me feel bad that many important source files are not visiable in the **Projects** panel. So...

- How does QtCreator decide whether to show a file?
- Is there any cmake command that can make arbitrary file to be visiable in QtCreator?

=======================

Some additional info:

My project is a C++ library with PerlXS interface. XS code is preprocessed into C code by **xsubpp**, and this action is added into cmake project via **add_custom_target**. However, the XS file is not added into **Porjects** panel by QtCreator. Besides, a project can have non-source text files such as README, Changes, etc..

Comment: You question already contains answer. QtCreator decide whether to show a file when this file used in project (add_executable, add_library). CMake commands add_executable, add_library can make arbitrary files to be visible. Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: @Sergey added more detailed info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see no reason to put something specific with project, when you can switch to "File System" browser in QtCreator.

[image]

But anyway, the answer still the same. If you wish to see something in project - add it to add_executable, add_library.

For example

```
set(DATA_FILE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/README.txt)
...
add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${SRC_FILES} ${GLB_HDR_FILES} ${DATA_FILE})
```

And now we can see README.txt in project

[image]

Same trick can be done for other files. Just add them to DATA_FILE variable.

Comment: Nice workaround, although it's kind of hackish hahaha. :)

Comment: It's 2020, with Qt Creator 4.12, and this still works :)

Comment: This approach is also useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43343854/639324