# How to list custom files using CMAKE in QtCreator?

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

Using `CMAKE` to manage a project under `QtCreator`, some useful files are not shown in the project browser (e.g. xml files, .ui files, etc.).

**Is there a way to explicitly add a custom file for being listed in the project using `CMAKE`?**

```
#*************************************************************************
# Indicate a related file for the project, only for convenient showing in
# project, does not mean dependency, inclusion, but just related.
function ("IndicateExternalFile" NAME )
    # TODO: No idea how to make this.

endfunction()
```

Tries up to now:

```
file( GLOB "test.xml") #Not showing.
```

Comment: I don't know how `QtCreator` does handle this but generally speaking you just add the "custom files" as source files to your library or executable CMake targets to show up in your IDE project

Comment: Is that not going to make the file required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

I've given it a try with [qt-creator](/questions/tagged/qt-creator) and you can just add the "custom files" as source files to your library or executable CMake targets to show up in your IDE project:

[image]

But I've to admit that does not work for non-existing/optional files.

So you may add `if (EXISTS ...)` checks to your function like the following example demonstrates:

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(CMakeTest)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

function(IndicateExternalFile _target)
    foreach(_file IN ITEMS ${ARGN})
        if ((IS_ABSOLUTE "${_file}" AND EXISTS "${_file}") OR
            (EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${_file}"))
            target_sources(${_target} PRIVATE "${_file}")
        endif()
    endforeach()
endfunction()

file(WRITE "text.xml" "")
IndicateExternalFile(${PROJECT_NAME} "text.xml" "test2.xml")
```

*Note*: You need an existing target to add "sources" with [`target_sources()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html).

Comment: Do you know any way to add those files to the target after or before the add_executable? I was looking `target_sources` but I could not make it to work.

Comment: @AdrianMaire Yes, I can add this later today to my answer. Which version of CMake do you use? Because for older versions (< 3.7) you would need to give a target name to your `IndicateExternalFile` function be able to add it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, that would be fantastic! My cmake version is required to be 3.0 compatible.

Comment: @AdrianMaire Ok. Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

You can add a custom target and bind the additional to this target.

Example:

```
add_custom_target(useful_files ALL 
    SOURCES
      MyUsefulFile.txt
      Read.me
      Version.txt
)
```

I use this in every subfolder. QtCreator shows the added files within the Projects list.

Btw: I avoid the usage of `file( GLOB ...)`. See the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob) for the reasons.